# Flutter Emulator - Why is Sqflite creating x.db-journal files and not removing them?

Tags: file, flutter, android-emulator, sqflite, journal

I am having problems with a larger application that is using sqflite.  So I created this simple app to test a few things and I noticed that the app is creating a journal file in the emulator and not removing it.  Is this by design or an issue with the emulator or sqflite?

If this is by design, I guess it would be common practice to have to cleanup these files along with the database file.  That seems like a bit messy but doable I guess.  I am hoping is it just a problem with the emulator.

[image: example journal file]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyClass myClass;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: AppWg());
  }
}

class AppWg extends StatefulWidget {
  AppWg({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AppWgState createState() => _AppWgState();
}

class _AppWgState extends State<AppWg> {
  MyClass myClass = MyClass();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test")), body: getView(context));
  }

  Widget getView(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("path:" + myClass.path),
        Text("message:" + myClass.message),
        RaisedButton(
            child: Text("action"),
            onPressed: () {
              onAction();
            })
      ],
    );
  }

  void onAction() {
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((dir) {
      String path = join(dir.path, "db1.db");
      print(path);
      myClass.createDb(path).then((result) {
        setState(() {});
      });
    });
  }
}

class MyClass {
  Database db;
  String path = "";
  String message = "";

  Future<bool> createDb(p) async {
    try {
      path = p;
      message = "attempting delete/create";
      File file = File(path);
      if (await file.exists()) {
        await file.delete();
      }
      if (!(await file.exists())) {
        db = await openDatabase(path, onConfigure: (db) {
          String qs = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON";
          db.execute(qs);
        });
        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");
        await db.close();
      } else {
        message = "Database still exists.";
      }
    } catch (e) {
      message = "Failed delete at path:" + path + ": Error is: " + e.message;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: check https://fileinfo.com/extension/db-journal (last paragraph in particular)

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the site resource.  That will come in handy.  What I still don't understand is why the transaction is getting created since I am not using a transaction.  And also why it persists since the descriptions seems to suggest it should be removed at the end of the transaction.

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-transaction/ - in the terminal i run `sqlite3` command line app and after `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` and some `INSERT ...` the journal is created and after `COMMIT;` it is deleted, why it is not deleted when using sqlite API? i dont know ;-)

Comment: @pskink this is sqflite package being used in Dart for a Flutter application.  So this is not the sqlite3 command line or traditional sqlite3 access as far as I know. Unless sqflite uses that under the hood.

Comment: yes it uses [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) C library under the hood